# Find all multipolygons from one table within another

Tags: postgresql, postgis

So, I've got two tables - PLUTO (pieces of land), and NYZMA (rezoning boundaries). They look like:

```
    pluto                   nyzma
id | geom                name | geom
--------------------     -------------------
 1 | MULTIPOLYGON(x)       A  | MULTIPOLYGON(a)
 2 | MULTIPOLYGON(y)       B  | MULTIPOLYGON(b)
```

And I want it to spit out something like this, assuming that PLUTO record 1 is in multipolygons A and B, and PLUTO record 2 is in neither:

```
pluto_id | nyzma_id
-------------------
    1    | [A, B]
    2    |
```

How do I, for every PLUTO record's corresponding geometry, cycle through each NYZMA record, and print the names of any whose geometry matches?

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables using the spatial function [ST_Contains](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Contains.html). Than use [GROUP BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) and [ARRAY_AGG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) in the main query:

```
WITH subquery AS ( 
    SELECT pluto.id, nyzma.name 
      FROM pluto LEFT OUTER JOIN nyzma 
      ON ST_Contains(nyzma.geom, pluto.geom)
    )
SELECT id, array_agg(name) FROM subquery GROUP BY id;
```